# Magento2: How can load all css and js files after 5 seconds on site load?

Tags: magento2, optimization

I want to load all css and js files after 5 seconds when site load. actually I am doing optimisation and css and js files taking so much time of load. I have minify js/css and merged css/js also. Anyone have an idea for that?

Comment: It's possible for js to load by adding delay only for your custom js and not for css, Use gulp to minify all the inline js that could save a bit

Comment: Okay, Thank you

Comment: Load of CSS , depend o your code and HTML structure and dom load time.If you your page size small, then css must load with 5.Every depends how you have develop your pages and pages size